# Download manager downloads a bin file if file name not specified (Google Cloud Storage URL)

Tags: android, google-cloud-storage, android-download-manager

I have a Google Cloud Storage download link and I am using Android DownloadManager to download the file, when I download the file without specifying the file name it ends up downloading a .bin file.

One more thing is: If I try to manually download the link from chrome browser, it works perfectly fine.

```
fun  downloadFile() {
    val uri = Uri.parse("...") //link to the file
    Environment
        .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
        .mkdirs()

    val request =
        DownloadManager.Request(uri)
            .setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED)
            //.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "file.jpg")

    val downloadManager = getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager
    downloadID = downloadManager.enqueue(request)
}
```

Comment: The way Android browser currently handles this by making a HEAD request and getting file info beforehand, source - https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_packages_apps_browser/blob/master/src/com/android/browser/DownloadHandler.java#L226

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general with HTTP, for a file to be downloaded with a desired filename, the server must set the `Content-Disposition` header to something like `attachment; filename="filename.jpg"`.  This can be set in GCS with [metadata](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/WorkingWithObjectMetadata#content-disposition).  After you set content-disposition in this way, DownloadManager should respect it when picking filenames.